# How would one craft a dsc that builds a package from multiple upstream source repositories

Tags: dpkg, git, packaging

This is a complex one releated specifically to Debian/Ubuntu packaging (i.e. making `.deb`s).

I've got a set of projects that are all currently separate. Using my real project (Jellyfin) here for simplicity.

There's a server component, a web component, and an ffmpeg component. Each has its own upstream source repository.

What I would like to do is build a single `debian/` config, i.e. `control`, `changelog`, `rules`, etc. that would:

(a) build all 3 parts
(b) package them all in their separate `.debs`
(c) have a single source (`.dsc`) archive out at the end.

So far, I've not found any examples of a project/package that is in this situation. Most seem to just have a single upstream code repo, and most of the tooling e.g. `git-buildpackage` seem built around that fact.

The most obvious way I can think to do this is using submodules inside of a parent Git repository that contains the `debian/` stuff. I've crafted `rules` that work for this, but the problem is that `dpkg-source` loses its brains in various trying to make a source archive. So rather than asking about those "Y"s, I'm questioning the "X" instead.

Does anyone know of an example of some package that does something like this?